# How to show a Splash Screen with Animation while activity is loading in background. (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-animation, splash-screen

The `MainActivity` of my Android app is takes a long time to load. So, I want to make a splash screen which will show until the `MainActivity` has finished loading i.e: all the work of the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` is done, after which the Splash Screen must be closed and the `MainActivity` launched. Furthermore, The Splash Screen has an animation on it.

*The onCreate method for the Splash Screen is:*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
    final Animation startRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.android_rotate_animation);
    startRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    imageView.startAnimation(startRotateAnimation);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}
```

The `SplashScreen` will finish in the above code after the time specified by `SPLASH_TIME_OUT`, which is a fixed integral constant.

*and* `android_rotate_animation.xml` *is:*

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="3000"
android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

**How should I make the** `SplashScreen` **only show until the** `MainActivity` **finishes loading?**

*I cannot use multiple image files for animation due to project restriction.*

**The SplashScreen is meant to behave like a loading screen. An animation will play on it (like a loading bar) until MainActivity has finished loading, after which MainActicity will launch.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can either move the data-loading into your SplashScreenActivity and start the MainActivity when data is loaded, or move ahowing a Splash-View to your MainActivity, where you initially just show the Splash-View until data is loaded and then hide that view or replace it with the actual view of the MainActivty.

**EDIT** I suggest, you use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform the loading asynchronously. You can update the progress bar in its onProgressUpdate() method and when work is done, in onPostExecute() you can hide the progress bar and show the normal layout.

Comment: How do i tell whether `MainActivity` has been loaded or not?

Comment: Do you mean the second approach I'm suggesting?

Comment: Yes, I meant the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
**create a custom theme for splash screen**

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/rotate</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
</style>
<!-- Animation for splash screen -->
<style name="DialogSlideAnim">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

**and apply Theme in to splash screen**

```
setTheme(R.style.DialogSlideAnim)
```

Comment: I don't want an animation for the activity. There is an image in the SplashScreen activity that I need to animate. Sort of like hoe the loading bar works in splash screens of many games